# A bound on the maximum $p$-th moment of a discrete martingale. Motivating examples or significance of the result?

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, stochastic-analysis, extreme-value-analysis

I was presented with the following result, and it was stressed that this was an important result:

Let $\{ X_t\}_{t \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a martingale. Then, for any $p>1$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have that $E\left[\max_{1 \leq j \leq n}\mid X_j \mid ^p \right] \leq \left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^p E[|X_n|^p]$.

As I understand this, the statement says that the p-th moment of the maximal value of the martingale up to time n is bounded by the p-th moment of the value at time n.

However, I fail to realize the depth and importance of this result. Specifically, I wonder:

- Is this result important for proving other results in stochastic analysis?
- Are there any intuitive examples where this result is used to gain understanding of a stochastic process?

Comment: It shows that if $(X_n)$ is a martingale such that $E|X_n|^{p} $ is bounded and $1<p<\infty$ then $X_n$ converges in $L^{p}$. This false for $p=1$ and not at all obvious for $p>1$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @KaviRamaMurthy! That's a connection I failed to realize, but absolutely of importance.